# Slicing and if statements (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, slice

Alright, I'm really struggling with this right now, some help would be appreciated.

Basically, say if I have a value like `2013` (the year)
I want to extract the `13` from `2013`, which I know how to do, through:
`int(str(y)[2::])`

However I want to possibly use an if statement(?) to confirm if the last two numbers on the numbers aren't `0`s, if they are, such as the year `2000`, then I have to ignore it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd test for a multiple of 100:

```
if y % 100 > 0:
    somevar = y % 100
```

or even just

```
if y % 100:
    somevar = y % 100
```

since numeric 0 is false in a boolean context.

You can avoid calculating the remainder twice:

```
remainder = y % 100
if remainder:
    somevar = remainder
```

This uses the `%` operator, which gives you the remainder, a much more efficient method than your `int(str(y)[2:])` round-about method:

```
>>> 2000 % 100
0
>>> 2013 % 100
13
```